# Using regex to remove multiple occurrences for anything in parentheses

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a dataframe in Pandas `test` with a column `Column1` where for any cases where there are parentheses, I want to remove the parentheses and the characters between the parentheses. So far I have:

```
test['Column1'].str.replace(r"\([^()]*\)","")
```

This is only working to remove a single set of parentheses. How would I extend the replace to remove all sets of parentheses?

Comment: Isn't a _record_ a line of _columns_ ?

Comment: You should do the recursion yourself, in other words run replace until it fails to replace.

Comment: `str.replace` replaces all occurrences.

Answer (score 2):

This might be impossible.  Consider that python does not support [recursive regular expressions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html). Given that balanced parenthesis is a form a recursive matching problem. The best you can do is make an assumption that parenthesis are balanced and match the first parenthesis to the last parenthesis. You could simply write a function to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

`str.replace` replaces all occurrences. While python does not support recursive regular expressions, the string replacement is taking care of multiple occurrences in this case.